# Existence of bounded analytic function on unbounded domain?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Given any proper open connected unbounded set $U$  in $\mathbb C$.Does there always exist a non constant bounded analytic function $ f\colon U \to \mathbb C$ ?

**Edit:** $U$ is any arbitrary domain. I don't have idea to do it. Please help.

Comment: Think about $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ 0\}$ and removable singularities.

Comment: If $U$ is simply connected the Riemann mapping theorem guarantees the existence of an analytic function $f:\>U\to D$.

Comment: This question has some relevance:  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/432810/27978.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No not always. Take $ U= \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Take a bounded analytic function on $U$. As it is bounded it can only have a removeable singularity at $0$. Thus it extends to an entire function, which must be constant.

On the other hand if the closure of $U$ is not all of $\mathbb{C}$ take a $z_0$ outside the closure of $U$  and consider $(z-z_0)^{-1}$.

This is not a full classification of all $U$ though, but you did not ask for this.

Comment: Does this change if we assume simple connectedness?

Comment: Yes. As you can use Riemann mapping theorem, in that case there always exists such a function.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: ... if the complement has at least two elements.

Comment: @MartinR I think RMT applies to non-empty proper simply connected open subsets of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: In that case you are right.

Answer (score 6):

No. Take $U=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{p\}$, and take $f$ bounded holomorphic on $U$. Then we can extend $f$ to the whole complex plane (a point is *removable*), but being bounded and entire, $f$ has to be constant.

Answer (score 5):

Take $f(z) = {1 \over z} $ on $U=\{z \mid |z|>1 \}$.

This example can be extended to any $U$ such that $U^c$ contains an open set.

Comment: But $U$ is any arbitrary domain?

Comment: Are you asking to show this for an arbitrary $U$ (that satisfies the conditions)?

Comment: Yeah,I'm asking for arbitrary $U$