# Show that this function is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which sets are removable for holomorphic functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159659/which-sets-are-removable-for-holomorphic-functions)
>   [Prove analyticity by Morera’s theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201312/prove-analyticity-by-moreras-theorem)

Let $f$ be a continuous complex-valued function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that it is analytic everywhere outside $[-a,a] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Show that it is in fact entire.

Comment: When you say *strip*, do you mean an actual strip $[-a+it,a+it]$, as $t\in\mathbb R$ varies, or you really want the subset $[-a,a]\subset\mathbb R$?

Comment: The latter one. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: This has been answered several times already.  Search for "Morera" and you'll find some answers.

Comment: Thanks! I can see how that could be used to solve this problem!

Comment: I started to type an answer but @WimC was faster.(+1)

Comment: Link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159659/which-sets-are-removable-for-holomorphic-functions