# Is $f$ an entire function?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous (here $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex plane) and 
$f$ is analytic everywhere on $\mathbb{C}$ except possibly on the interval $[-1,1]$. 
Is $f$ an entire function?

Comment: You know Morera's theorem?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201312/prove-analyticity-by-moreras-theorem) answers your question in more generality.