# Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\Omega - \{z_0\}$. Then $g$ defined by $g(z)=(z-z_0)f(z)$ for $z\in \Omega-\{z_0\}$, $g(z_0)=0$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Edit: Also given
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} (z-z_0)f(z)=0
$$

It's easy to see that $g$ is holomorphic on $\Omega-\{z_0\}$, so we only need to worry about $g'(z_0)$. By definition, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0} &= \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{(z-z_0)f(z)-0}{z-z_0} \\
&= \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} f(z).
\end{align*}
Thus, we need only to show that $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)$ exists. This is where I'm stuck. It makes perfect sense that if $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$, and $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=0$, then $f$ is continuous at $z_0$, but I'm having trouble showing this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: the question changed.

Now your new assumption makes $z_0$ a removable singularity for $f$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity

So you can extend $f$ holomorphically over $z_0$.

In particular, $g$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added some more constraints that should make this valid.

Comment: But $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} (z-z_0)f(z)\neq 0$.

Comment: @WilliamStagner Yes... Give me the time to adjust... Now I have updated my answer.

Comment: @WilliamStagner You're most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that $g$ is continuous.  A function that is holomorphic away from a point and continuous at that point is holomorphic.  See the question [Which sets are removable for holomorphic functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159659/which-sets-are-removable-for-holomorphic-functions) for much more along these lines.

If you look at the proof that $f$ has a removable singularity from julien's link, you'll notice that the trick is to multiply by $z-z_0$ yet again to smooth things out more.  The function $h(z)=(z-z_0)^2f(z)$, $h(z_0)=0$, is not only easily seen to be continuous, but this time using your method you also see that $h'(z_0)=0=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}h'(z)$, so $h$ is holomorphic.  Since $h$ has a zero of order at least $2$ at $z_0$, one can see that $\dfrac{h(z)}{z-z_0}$ (your function $g$) and $\dfrac{h(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}$ are also holomorphic, e.g., using power series as in the link from julien's answer.