# Is a continuous function that is analytic on the immaginary axis entire?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have given a function $f$ which is continuous on $\Bbb C$ and analytic on the imaginary axis and I have to prove that $f$ is analytic in $\Bbb C$, hence , $f$ is entire.

Would anybody please help me solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Given the wide variety of interpretations, it'd be good to update your question on what you mean by analytic on the imaginary axis. I know you've done so in a comment, but it's better to have it in the question itself

Answer (score 2):

This is not true: consider $f(z)=\min(\Re z,1)+i\Im z$

Comment: this is a theorem, hence it must be true. Would you please be kind and explain why do you think this is not true(proof)?

Comment: @tea I don't know what you think you have read, but the function I have written is continuous on $\Bbb C$ and holomorphic on $\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \Re z<1\}$, as you can check for yourself.

Comment: @Tea Can you give us the **precise** statement of that "theorem"?  It can't be what you wrote...

Comment: Let f(z) be continuous on C and analytic on {z| Im(z)=/0}.Prove that f must be analytic in whole complex plane.   (I wrote =/ instead of "different from")

Comment: @Gae.S. , @ Robert Israel , I've found this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548515/a-continous-function-on-g-complex-analytic-on-g-setminus-s-is-analytic-on , it looks similar , but I'm not sure if it helps... (sorry)

Comment: Do you see the difference between "$\text{Im}(z) \ne 0$" and "**on** the imaginary axis"?

Comment: @Tea $\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \Im z\ne0\}$ isn't the imaginary axis, which would be $\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \Re z=0\}$, but the complement of the real line.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (for the question you meant to ask): Do you know Morera's theorem?

Comment: Yes I do . And how do you think I can use it?

Comment: It suffices to show the integral around any triangle is $0$.  If the real axis intersects the triangle, look at the parts on either side.

Comment: would you please be kind and send me the proof of this theorem using the Morera's theorem , because I'm not sure if I understood what you meant by that?Thank you.